# How can I set a tracking cookie so returning visitors are directed to a page they choose during first visit?

Tags: php, wordpress

My home page has 4 links to different sub-pages (page-1, page-2, etc.), when a visitor selects a page (i.e. /page-1/) I want them to be routed directly to that page on their return visit to the site. I'm trying to use a cookie to store the selected page and check the cookie on return to re-direct to the previously selected URL.

```
function set_pref_cookie(){

    $root = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if ($root !='/'){
        setcookie('pref_sel',$root, time()+60*60*24*5, "/");
    }

    if (isset($_COOKIE['pref_sel'])){
        header('Location:' .  $_COOKIE['pref_sel']);
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('init','set_pref_cookie');
```

This works to set the cookie, but on return to the site, I'm getting a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a redirect loop cause :

- i navigate to page-1
- you put cookie to page-1
- you redirect me to page-1
- you put cookie to page-1
- you redirect me to page-1
- and so on ..

Before redirect, just check if i'm not already on the good page :)

Just change this :

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['pref_sel'])){
        header('Location:' .  $_COOKIE['pref_sel']);
        exit;
    }
```

to this :

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['pref_sel']) && $_COOKIE['pref_sel'] != $root){
        header('Location:' .  $_COOKIE['pref_sel']);
        exit;
    }
```

And it will do not redirect in infinite loop

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the redirect loop. I have made a change to the cookie method I'm using and still running into some issues. New question posted here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026729/set-tracking-cookie-from-link-using-url-query-redirect-to-selected-link-on-retu)

Comment: The answer here is still the answer for your new question