# Set tracking cookie from link using URL query, redirect to selected link on return visit

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have page with 4 links, when someone clicks on one of the links I want to set a cookie to store the selected link, then when they return to the site, the cookie redirects them to the link they previously selected. Since I only want the 4 links to set a cookie I'm using a query string (?sel=p1) in the link and checking for that to set the cookie.

```
function set_pref_cookie(){

    if (isset($_GET['sel'])) {
        $root = $_GET['sel'];

        if ($root = 'p1'){
            $cookie_var = '/page1/';
        } else if ($root = 'p2'){
            $cookie_var = '/page2/';
        } else if ($root = 'p3'){
            $cookie_var = '/page3/';
        } else if ($root = 'p4'){
            $cookie_var = '/page4/';
        }

    } else {
      $root = '';
    }

    if ($root !=''){
        setcookie('pref_sel',$_COOKIE['sel'] = $cookie_var, time()+60*60*24*5, "/");
    }

    if (isset($_COOKIE['pref_sel']) && $_COOKIE['pref_sel'] != ''){
        header('Location:' .  $_COOKIE['pref_sel']);
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('init','set_pref_cookie');
```

The issue is, all 4 links set the same value in the cookie `/page1/`
, and, on return to the site, I'm getting a redirect loop.

I've also tried checking for an empty cookie

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['pref_sel']) && !empty($_COOKIE['pref_sel']) ){
```

but same result.

Comment: if (isset($_COOKIE['pref_sel']) && $_COOKIE['pref_sel'] != $root){
        header('Location:' .  $_COOKIE['pref_sel']);
        exit;
    }

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this and the issue is still there. $cookie_var is set to /page-1/ no matter what link is clicked, and going to home still has a redirect issue.

Comment: yes, cause your for setting cookies are with only one equal sign (affectation) instead of 2 equal signs == (comparison)

Answer (score 0):

To refer to all the comments in your first ticket, and this one (please don't use 2 questions for the same problem)

=> Redirection with cookie without loop : ok fixed by the correction i gave you and explained to you in the first question.

=> second problem : you're always redirected to page-1.
=> please fix this part of you're code like this :

```
if ($root == 'p1'){
            $cookie_var = '/page1/';
        } else if ($root == 'p2'){
            $cookie_var = '/page2/';
        } else if ($root == 'p3'){
            $cookie_var = '/page3/';
        } else if ($root == 'p4'){
            $cookie_var = '/page4/';
        }
```

You also should add an else case cause your $cookie_var could have sometimes empty value.

=> third, what do you want to achieve with your setcookie with an affectation ?

```
setcookie('pref_sel',$_COOKIE['sel'] = $cookie_var, time()+60*60*24*5, "/");
```

you should only do this :

```
setcookie('pref_sel', $cookie_var, time()+60*60*24*5, "/");
```

=> to debug, comment you're redirection and replace it by

```
echo $_COOKIE['pref_sel'];
```

Comment: @shacker : is my last comment your answer ?